# How To create ORACLE Sequence to Populate Dimension Table based off another table

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence, dimension

EDIT: I revised my original question for clarity. Hopefully this helps explain what I'm trying to accomplish more clearly.

I have a standard SQL table `VEHICLES` and I changed its name to `OLTP_VEHICLES` with a `RENAME` statement.

I created a new VEHICLES table as a dimension table that is the "beginning" of my star schema for this DB.

I now need to accomplish the following:

"For the `vehicleCode` primary key column, use an Oracle Sequence to populate the values. For the `vehicleDescription` column, use a concatenated combination of `vehicleMake` and `vehicleModel` from the `OLTP_VEHICLES table`."

I need to accomplish this by using a PL/SQL block to populate the description column by selecting the `vehicleMake` and `vehicleModel` from the `OLTP_VEHICLES` table and then inserting the concatenated combination into the `VEHICLES` Dimension table, via a cursor in a loop.

With this instruction, I am totally baffled. I think where I was confusing you fine folks before was the fact that I was leaving out the "second part" involving the insertion of the `vehicleMake` and `vehicleModel` concatenation.

Does this help explain better what I'm after? If not, I'm deeply sorry. I'm so confused on this that I'm even having trouble explaining it. Thanks again for your assistance.

```
CREATE TABLE VEHICLES
(vehicleVIN     VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
vehicleType     VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL CHECK (lower(vehicleType) IN ('compact', 'midsize', 'fullsize', 'suv', 'truck')),
vehicleMake     VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
vehicleModel        VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
vehicleWhereFrom    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL CHECK (lower(vehicleWhereFrom) IN ('maryland','virginia','washington, d.c.')),
vehicleWholesaleCost    DECIMAL(9,2)    NOT NULL,
vehicleTradeID      INT);

INSERT INTO VEHICLES
(vehicleVIN,vehicleType,vehicleMake,vehicleModel,vehicleWhereFrom,vehicleWholesaleCost,vehicleTradeID)
VALUES
('147258HHE91K3RT','compact','chevrolet','spark','Maryland',20583.00,NULL);
INSERT INTO VEHICLES
(vehicleVIN,vehicleType,vehicleMake,vehicleModel,vehicleWhereFrom,vehicleWholesaleCost,vehicleTradeID)
VALUES
('789456ERT0923RFB6','Midsize','ford','Taurus','washington, d.c.',25897.22,1);
INSERT INTO VEHICLES
(vehicleVIN,vehicleType,vehicleMake,vehicleModel,vehicleWhereFrom,vehicleWholesaleCost,vehicleTradeID)
VALUES
('1234567890QWERTYUIOP','fullsize','Lincoln','towncar','Virginia',44222.10,NULL);
INSERT INTO VEHICLES
(vehicleVIN,vehicleType,vehicleMake,vehicleModel,vehicleWhereFrom,vehicleWholesaleCost,vehicleTradeID)
VALUES
('WER234109TEO458GZ','SUV','Chevrolet','suburban','Maryland',52789.00,2);

ALTER TABLE VEHICLES RENAME TO OLTP_VEHICLES;

CREATE TABLE VEHICLES
(vehicleCode        VARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY,
vehicleDescription  VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL);
```

I also put this into SQL Fiddle if anyone wants to test something: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2de3ae

Thanks!

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?  `12c` introduced IDENTITY columns that make this much simpler.

Comment: Your `vehicevin` column seems to contain alphanumeric values and hence should `vehicleCode`? So, you cannot have a sequence on such values anyway. Other option is to have an `Insert Trigger` on your `OLTP_VEHICLES` table.

Comment: @MatBailie unfortunately still using 11g.

Comment: @KaushikNayak, yes they are alphanumeric since the "vin's" are composed of both letters and numbers. vehicleCode is the PK for the dimension table VEHICLES. If you are asking if vehicleVIN should be copied to vehicleCode then yes, that is what I am after. I've been told this is accomplished by a sequence, even with the attribute types that I've listed.

Comment: This is how to create a "surrogate key" from a sequence : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/8fc16/1 - From that point on-wards *(in "fact tables", etc)* you refer to the `id` column.  That way if the VIN has a typo *(for example)* you can correct the VIN in one place without having to correct all the other occurrences in other tables.  Additionally, as the datatype is much smaller it will improve the performance of joins, indexes, etc.

Comment: Understood @matBailie. Thank you. Is it possible to use a sequence to just "copy" the vehicleVIN data to the vehicleCode column? I looked at what you created and although I really like your logic and approach, the specific instruction that I've received is to work off of the data that I already have and not create any new columns for the existing tables. Essentially, creating a major flaw in the code as you noted due to the issue with VIN correlation, but I also have to do what I'm asked, even if it isn't "best practice...."

Comment: @StevenC - The instruction makes no sense.  A sequence is a device for counting in integers.  Nothing to do with copying any values from anywhere to anywhere.  You need to go back and ask for clearer instructions, as at the moment you may as well be asking "can I copy a value from one table to another using a colour". 
 *(Not to mention that using a string as a primary key in a dimension table in a star schema is a generically bad idea.)*  I suspect that if the terms `sequence` and `dimension table` are being used, it's to do what I described.  *(That is the normal use-case of a sequence.)*

Comment: A rough example of dimension tables and sequences...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db05e7/9

Comment: If the term `sequence` wasn't mentioned in the instructions you've received, it may just be that you've heard the term yourself and that's lead you down a blind alley?  *(Well, actually a better route, but one you've been told not to follow?)*  Perhaps what you want is to create new rows in the second table, if they don't already exist?  If so, just read the `INSERT dim_vehicle_type` statement in my second SQL fiddle *(Inserting into one table, from another table, while checking if a value already exists)*.

Comment: @MatBailie the specific instruction is "For the vehicleCode primary key column, use an oracle sequence to populate the values. Now I wasn't provided with any output data as an example, so maybe I'm just heading down the wrong path altogether. I need to clarify as to what "values" he wants to see. Thanks again for helping me out.

Comment: @MatBailie Revised the question to (hopefully) clarify.

Comment: Please double check the table definition for the new table, it sounds like `vehicleCode` should be a `NUMBER`.  Equally, it sounds like you should have `Make` and `Model` as separate columns.  Using concatenation to make an identifier is weak *(for example `aa` + `b` == `a` + `ab`)*, where as having separate fields is both robust and easy to understand / maintain.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/6a42a/3

Comment: @MatBailie Once again, I agree wholeheartedly. It's unfortunate, but I need to concat them for this assignment. But for now, I'm just trying to get the initial population of vehicleCode and description to work. Instead of the concat, for now I'm just `INSERT`ing the vehicleMake. Still getting errors though. Would you mind taking a look at this if you have a moment? Keep in mind that I HAVE to complete this via PL/SQL with a cursor/loop, so that's why I'm taking this approach.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f9e570/5

Comment: Is this school work?  There isn't another reason I can think of that you ***have to*** use a cursor...  Here's a revision to my fiddle to use concatenation, but I'm not going to needlessly write it with a cursor...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1acb0/3

Comment: @MatBailie Yes, it is. I thought I had mentioned that already. My apologies for not. And yes, the instruction says to perform it by a PL/SQL block with a cursor in a loop...

Comment: Then I suggest that you study what I've already given you, to re-work it as a cursor, and/or open another question with the full and accurate details :)

Comment: Thanks @MatBailie. Will do.

Comment: I think I got it @MatBailie. Going to run against my NOVA DB tonight and will post an answer if it works. Took your advice and made it work for the instructions that I had to follow. Thanks again for the help/guidance. Here's an SQL Fiddle link if you're interested in what I did: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/48376/3

Comment: You define a cursor, then you loop through the cursor, then you insert from the table, never using the value in the cursor, ever, at all, even once...  This means that you do ***all*** the inserts on the first loop, and then 0 inserts on each subsequent loop.  Also, you repeat the `LOWER() || LOWER()` snippet unnecessarily.  Try this : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/48376/8

Comment: Thanks @MatBailie. Still learning here.

Comment: @MatBailie - one issue: when looping multiple times (as demonstrated by your cursor loop example), the query only lists some of the vehicles because of the WHERE clause that doesn't assign a vehicleCode to any vehicleDescriptions that are already assigned a code. For example if the vehicleDescription `Honda Pilot` were already assigned the vehicleCode `1` via the sequence, the next vehicle that has a `vehicleDescription' of `Honda Pilot` will not be assigned a new `vehicleCode`. Do you know of a simple way to edit the WHERE clause or should I just stick with my cursor loop since it works?

Comment: That's a misunderstanding of dimension tables. If you're creating rows based on make and model then you're creating a DimVehicleMakeAndModel, such that both vehicles in that example have the same MakeAndModel ID. You would then also have a DimVehicle table, based on the VIN to ensure they both get separate entries in that table. Such a table wouldn't have Make or Model columns, instead they'd have a MakeAndModelID column. See my earlier fiddles for examples.

Comment: You're right @Matbailie. My bad. Just confused on the entire thing, but very thankful for your guidance. Your last revision is what I needed. Thanks again. Do you want to post it as the answer or should I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, after lots of research, trial and error, and of course, help from @MatBailie. Here's the solution I was after:

```
--Oracle sequence to populate primary key values in VEHICLES dimension table

DROP SEQUENCE SEQ_VEHICLES;
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_VEHICLES START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER VEHICLES_PK
BEFORE INSERT ON VEHICLES FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SELECT SEQ_VEHICLES.NEXTVAL INTO :new.vehicleCode FROM DUAL;
END;
/

--PL/SQL Block to populate the description column via a cursor in a loop w/concatenation

DECLARE
CURSOR vehDesCur IS
    SELECT LOWER(vehicleMake) || ' ' || LOWER(vehicleModel)   AS vehicleDescription
    FROM OLTP_VEHICLES;
BEGIN
FOR oltp_data IN vehDesCur
LOOP
    INSERT INTO VEHICLES (vehicleDescription)
        SELECT oltp_data.vehicleDescription
        FROM dual
        WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT *
               FROM VEHICLES v
              WHERE v.vehicleDescription = oltp_data.vehicleDescription);
END LOOP;
END;
/
```